# How to use instance of a class in its own method for another instance?

Tags: java, methods, instance

I have two cases:

Case 1: I want to use one instance of a class while using a method of that class for another instance.

Case 2: I want to use one instance of a class while using a method of another class.

I will explain both the cases with the help of codes. I am new to JAVA and hence, don't really understand all the basics.

CASE 1:

```
public class Sum {

  public int var_one ;
  public int var_two ;
  public int total ;

  public int calculate_total(){
    total = var_one + ......// In place of these dots I want to use many[i-1].var_one,                                  i.e. the value of var_one of instance many[2] for                                        instance many[3] and so on. HOW CAN I DO THIS ???
      return total;
    }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    // Creating instances
    Sum [] many = new Sum [5];

    // Initializing instances
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
      many[i] = 0;
      }
    }

  // Assigning values
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
      many[i].var_one = 1;
      many[i].var_two = many[i].var_one + 1;
      many[i].total = many[i].calculate_total();
      }
    }


  }
```

CASE 2:

```
  public class See {
    public int once ;
    public int colour;

    public int assign_once_colour(){
      once = 0;
      colour = once + 1;
      return colour;
      }
    public static void main(String[] args){
      See [] name = new See [5];

      for (i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
        name [i].colour = name [i].assign_once_colour();
        }
      }
    }

  public class Sum {

    public int var_one ;
    public int var_two ;
    public int total ;
    }

 public int calculate_total(){
    total = var_one + ......// In place of these dots I want to use name[i-1].colour,                                  i.e. the value of colour of instance name[2] for                                        instance many[3] and so on. HOW CAN I DO THIS ???
      return total;
    }

public static void main(String[] args){
    // Creating instances
    Sum [] figure = new Sum [5];

    // Initializing instances
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
      figure[i] = 0;
      }
    }

  // Assigning values
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
      figure[i].var_one = 1;
      figure[i].var_two = many[i].var_one + 1;
      figure[i].total = many[i].calculate_total();
      }
    }

 }

}
```

I hope I could explain my doubt properly.

Comment: Please don't use stack snippets for Java - they are intended for Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Case 1: I want to use one instance of a class while using a method of
>   that class for another instance.

This is hard to see based on the code.

`// In place of these dots I want to use many[i-1].var_one,`

That line above doesn't represent a method according to your code. That's an integer. So I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to say here but I think your wording or terminology is a bit off.

> Case 2: I want to use one instance of a class while using a method of
>   another class.

`In place of these dots I want to use name[i-1].colour,` is basically an identical example. That's another integer not a method. So, again, it's a bit difficult to understand what you mean but if your code is an indicator of what you're actually wanting then I can say...

You can't. In both cases you are using arrays whose scopes are limited to the `main` method. You can't access it from an instance of `Sum`.

What you can do is add a parameter to your `calculateSum` method like so...

`public int calculate_total(int other) { ... }`

That way you have the integer value of the single element from those arrays you're looking for. The parameters passed in would be `var_one` and `colour` of the elements. This way you can have a simple integer addition.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured out how to do it, your reply helped a lot..!!